# how to create new dataframe with schema generated from_json values of columns generated by pivoting a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a dataframe with following schema.

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

It is first pivoted on a column "value".

```
val pivot_df = df.groupBy("id","key").pivot("type").agg(first("value"))
```

The "value" column's data may contains of nested json . So earlier i was converting the whole "value" column to get the required schema .

```
val schema = spark.read.json(df.select("value").as[String]).schema

val res_df = df.select($"id",$"type",$"key",from_json($"value",schema).as("s")).select("id","type","key","s.*")
```

But now i need to first pivot it on "value" column data and then read from json of all the new generated columns . Can someone suggest what code changes should be applied?

Comment: could you share the sample data input or `df.show()`? it will be easy for me to investigate?

Comment: you are using spark reader json wrong. `spark.read.json` takes a string *path to data*, not string *data*. You should specify your json `schema` manually like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64764317/select-few-columns-from-nested-array-of-struct-from-a-dataframe-in-scala/64773230#64773230 and after pass it to `from_json` function.